# Heap Analytics measure time spent on each div section

Tags: reactjs, heap-analytics

I have a very big web page made using React TypeScript. The page has multiple sections. To reach a particular section user has to scroll to the section.
I want to analyze the time spent by user on each section.
I am using Heap Analytics.